# How to dynamically get the content width of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am developing an application in AngularJS. I have a div that looks like this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="role">
  Sign Up
</div>
```

How can I find out the div content width dynamically, based on screen size? Like in the picture below, **Sign Up**'s width is 52.36px

[image]

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: A better question is "why do you need to know"? Because almost always "trying to get the actual rendered dimensions" turns out to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're trying to do something, and you're asking about a problem with your solution, rather than also mentioning the original problem so that people can tell you whether or not your solution even makes sense.

Comment: You really need Angular to get an Element width? What about `myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width` (floating point Number)? Or `myDiv.offsetWidth` (integer)? Or `myDiv.clientWidth` (no borders and no margin integer)

Comment: Than there's the `resize` Event.... Are you sure that all you need in not just CSS and `@media`?

Answer (score 1):

As @Roko C. Buljn commented, this is pretty easy:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="foobar" class="role">
  Sign Up
</div>
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById("foobar").getBoundingClientRect().width)
  console.log(document.getElementById("foobar").clientWidth)
  console.log(document.getElementById("foobar").offsetWidth)
</script>
```